# How to re-access properties panel after misclicked by accident?

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, properties, panel

[image]

I usually change the segments & rings at the properties panel after generated an object. The problem is when I misclick, it disappears and couldn't find re-opening option. I have to delete the existing object and recreate another one.

Are there any ways to access this panel w/o creating same object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut for this function is F9 key on your keyboard, it should appear again

Comment: Thank you. now I can escape from this redundant limbo re-creating hell.